# What file is being viewed in the elements tab in google web dev tools?

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools

When I click inspect element in Chrome, I would like to see what file is being displayed. I can't find any place in the elements tab that shows what file is being displayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there would be a way to label the elements that are being displayed there as being from any one file; they may be rendered dynamically by code in many external files.